# XCode breakpoint condition error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.4

I have this breakpoint condition:

```
[string isEqualToString:@"dummy"]
```

, but I always receive this error in the console:

> error: no known method '-isEqualToString:'; cast the message send to the method's return type

What am I doing wrong?

XCode version is 4.4.1, the debugger is LLDB.

Comment: can you add more code.. so that it can be clearer

Comment: Is `string` the name of your variable?

Answer (score 9):

I tried the conditional breaking point today and found the answer. Cast the return value to BOOL in your condition will fix this:

```
    (BOOL)[string isEqualToString:@"dummy"]
```

(This error will be raised even if the `string` is an NSString.)

Comment: That is right, you need to include the return type. Apple does document this, but it is easy to miss: "The breakpoint is triggered only if the condition is true (for example, i == 24). You can use any variables that are in the current scope for that breakpoint.
**You must cast an function calls to the appropriate return type.**" That last bit applies to method calls, as well. From the [Xcode User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html).

Comment: Although this solution appears to work, maybe I'm missing something (possible as I'm new to IOS dev) but this seems slightly counter-intuitive given that NSString.isEqualToString() returns a (BOOL) anyway,according to the NSString.h header file (???).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure "string" is the NSString type object!

Answer (score 0):

I think your "string" is character, number or urls type.
"string" must be in NSString type.